# Repo Sync a particular folder

Tags: git, android-source

I am trying to get the source code for the android os.
How do I repo sync a particular folder from the master branch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Partial checkouts are not supported with Git.

You could try using [git-subtree](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) for, after cloning the all repo, splitting part of that repo into your own project repo.

That said, if you are talking about one of the "[projects](https://github.com/android)" in the Android, they are Git repos, and can be managed with the tool "**[repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html)**".
See also "[Where can I browse Android source code on-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line)"

**Installing Repo:**

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
$ mkdir working-directory-name
$ cd working-directory-name
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

**Synchronizing your client**

**To synchronize the files for all available projects:**

```
$ repo sync
```

**To synchronize the files for selected projects**:

```
$ repo sync project1 project2 ...
```

Comment: How can I list available projects in repo?

Comment: @endryha: I have fixed the links in that answer and added some source of information for listing Android projects and browsing their code sources.

Comment: listing all the project with `repo forall -c 'echo "$REPO_PATH -- $REPO_PROJECT"'` for more info see: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-os-dev/xBtwK0RqRws

Comment: @0x90 ok, I would still be interested in the exact title of that thread on groups.google.com.

Comment: How I wish I have seen it earlier!!! I download all the source, and delete lots of files from my disk to get free room.