# where can I find httpsURLConnection source code?

Tags: android, eclipse

in Eclipse on my PC, I am debugging my app and seeing exception like:

> at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:146)

Where can I find source code of HttpsURLConnection?

My environment is:
PC, Eclipse Galileo, Android API level 4 (Platform 1.6),
Eclipse Installation Details shows "Eclipse.org, Apache Commons Httpclient, 3.1.0.v20080605-1035)

Comment: I would focus more on what caused it in your code. These libraries tend to be fairly well documented such that you don't need to see the code to find out why they're failing on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a tutorial on getting android source code and putting it into eclipse. maybe that can help but i'm not sure. [Link](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/browsing-android-source-in-eclipse/)

edit:
This might actually be more direct for your question
[Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.java#HttpsURLConnection)

I basically found the above link from this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449763/675032)

it has a lot of general source code viewing solutions. hope maybe that can help.

Comment: Thanks logicbird. I downloaded apache harmony 5.0 from [http://harmony.apache.org/download.cgi] and it was importing javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection that your link shows.