# Where is the source code for Android's web browser?

Tags: android-source

Since Android has such pathetic documentation, I'm looking for the source code for the browser so I can see what objects it provides to JavaScript. Where should I look? Is there an online source code browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's in the Git repository:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/android-3.2.4_r1/WebCore/xml/XMLHttpRequest.h

**Edit:**

The applications are now mirrored on [github](https://github.com/android). You can find the browser here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser.git

Answer (score 2):

Or try [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/): You can even throw a stack trace at it and it shows all relevant java files in all platform versions.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the link below in case you need more options

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser