# Who makes the Android stock web browser?

Tags: android, browser, web

The stock web browser on Android doesn't have any kind of "about" screen or information.  What company develops it?  Is it Google?  Is it open-source?  If so, is the source part of the Android OS source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It primarily developed by Google. Also, it is open source.

Comment: OK, is the source part of the Android project repo?

Comment: Yes it is. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962368/where-is-the-source-code-for-androids-web-browser