# How do you create the Browser layout (search bar on top, webview on bottom)?

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to mimic the default android Browser app layout, which has a "search_bar" on top and then a "webview" right below it. The user can scroll both items up, all the while the scroll bar only appears to the right of the webview (not both the webview and the search bar).

I've tried putting both the webview and the searchbar into a scrollview, but this shows the scrollbar next to the search_bar.

[image: a busy cat2]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to mimic the exact layout of default browser have a look at it's source code:

[Where can I find Android source code online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line)

If you need only browser source have a look here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser

From what I can see (a quick look at it) it is more complicated layout, but you may start analysing it from:

```
Browser\res\layout\browser_subwindow.xml
```

which directly includes `WebView`. This file is directly loaded by `Tab`... Go ahaed and analyse it on your own it is pretty simple as it is a regular Android application.

Hope it helps.