# Android tools doesnt show up on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-juno, eclipse-adt

I've installed the latest JRE, eclipse and I have the ADT plugin installed in eclipse. Somehow the android tools don't show up in the window. Instead, there are blank spaces where it should've been. Any help would be appreciated. [image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Restart Eclipse. If no changes, launch eclipse from the command line verbosely, and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Have you specifed the SDK from Windows->Preference-> Android->SDK Location ?

Answer (score 3):

Switch to the Java perspective (you are currently in the 'Resource' perspective): Window->Open Perspective->Java (you may need to select from the Other dialog box).

If you don't see Java as an option, you may have downloaded Eclipse classic, rather than Eclipse for Java Developers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to close and restart eclipse ? Also, make sure you have the sdk plugin installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) properly installed?

Was Eclipse restarted after that?

You can also download a [Android Developer Bundle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) that contains all what you need (Eclipse, ADT) except JDK.

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is that your buttons are simply not visible, it's just matter of adding them to your toolbar. Just right click on your toolbar and hit Customize, On the **Tool Bar Visibility** tab make sure **Android SDK and AVD Manager** is selected. That should do the trick.

[image]