# Where can I find the implementation of APIs in Android?

Tags: android, api, implementation

Is it possible to see the code on how the APIs in Android work?
Say, I want to see the implementation of method `setContentView()` or `setStroke()`.
I am wondering if the implementation of these APIs are exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Chrome-flavored browser, you can install the [Android SDK Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin) extension, which:

- Adds an `ad` search to the "omnibox" (a.k.a., address/search bar in Chrome), so `ad AdapterView` would take you right to the `AdapterView` documentation
- Adds a "(view source)" link to the JavaDocs for each class that brings up the source code to that class

Comment: This is perfect and works flawless. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Android is open source. You can find all the code from here: http://source.android.com/

Answer (score 2):

At this site you can find and browse the source code for all Android versions:
http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416821/977090

Basically, just install "Sources for Android SDK" from Android SDK Manager.