# How to see whats inside android classes?

Tags: java, android

i have been using android studio for an year now and i know what some classes do but i am just keen to know whats inside those methods in the classes. if I go di that class by pressing Ctrl+click it takes me to class but can't see what is inside the class methods.and google code search has shut down last year.where do i find core android classes?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-find-android-source-code-online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android SDK Manager you can download sources. I'm not sure how you get to the SDK manager in Studio because I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416821/3857465),

> Just open the Android SDK Manager and select the Sources for Android SDK of the API level you are trying to support and click Install packages.

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sdk_manager.htm) on how to find and use SDK manager.