# how to get android 4.0.3 source

Tags: android, android-source

i denfinitely know that there is offical article,http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and showing how to fetch the source.
But anyway,in my country,i can not get this.Can anyone show me how to get the archive file of that source?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line

Answer (score 3):

You can download it from here:

[4.0.3 source download](http://concentriclivers.com/android_source/)

Answer (score 2):

Does your country have access to GitHub? If so, the Android source is available [here](https://github.com/android).