# Android Froyo Phone app source

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want to learn something from Android Froyo phone application. I downloaded source from [github](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_phone), but that one was for ICS not for Froyo.

Does anyone know how can I download only phone application instead of downloading Froyo image. 
If that isn't possible then kindly please guide me downloading android Froyo source.

Comment: You can browse the source online. [Here] is a thread


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I downloaded source from github , but that one was for ICS not for Froyo,

The GitHub repo you linked to has branches for froyo and other versions.

Comment: hi man, i also need phone app code for ICS, can you please give link for source code of phone app, thanks in advance.