# online source browser for Android

Tags: android

Is there any web application that you know of where I can browse the android library source code? I'd also be interested in downloading a version of that alone(and not the whole version).

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line)?

Comment: Please check the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse the sourcecode on grepcode - http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android

The android sdk also has the option of downloading the sources for ICS forward.